# Problemas agrupando con ArrayList

Tags: java

Buenas noches a todos ! 
Parece mentira que ande atascado en una tarea muy sencilla , tengo el siguiente código java que consiste en un simple constructor que contiene un entero.

Si o si tengo que utilizar Java 7 par la implementación.

```
List<Prueba> prueba = new ArrayList<Prueba>();
prueba.add(new Prueba(1,"Prueba"));
prueba.add(new Prueba(3,"Prueba1"));
prueba.add(new Prueba(2,"Prueba2"));
prueba.add(new Prueba(2,"Prueba2"));
prueba.add(new Prueba(1,"Prueba"));
System.out.println("#1 normal for loop");              
for (int i = 0; i < prueba.size(); i++) {                    
  System.out.println(prueba.get(i).getPrueba());
}
```

Pues bien , tengo un problema necesito agrupar los items repetidos y por otro lado contar cuantas veces están repetidos los elementos.

Alguna ayuda ? Gracias ! :)

Comment: Repetidos según que criterio? Por el número, el texto o ambos?

Comment: Podría darse por el número o String ya que estos datos se obtienen de una base de datos . es que lo que no me sale es lo mas chorra jajaja .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más cómoda para realizar ese conteo es utilizando un `Map`, donde la clave sería el atributo de la clase `Prueba` por el que deseas agrupar (en nuestro caso el `String`) y contar las repeticiones y el valor sería la cantidad de veces que se repite dicho atributo (tener bien claro que aquí lo que estamos haciendo es agrupar por un atributo cualquiera, el cual debemos estar convencidos que si se repite indica que se trata de la misma prueba).

```
    Map<String, Integer> groupingMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Prueba item : prueba) {
        Integer count = groupingMap.get(item.getPrueba());
        groupingMap.put(item.getPrueba(), count == null ? 1 : ++count);
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias !